# How to read items from request when creating payment with multiple items?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm setting up a site using an Express.js server and am trying to implement the *paypal-node-sdk* npm module. The website will be used to sell my books. A user can add books to a cart and then click *Checkout* with PayPal. When clicked, this should send the contents of the cart to the `paypal.payment.create()` function, which will be used to create the user's payment information.

I've taken the boilerplate code from the *paypal-node-sdk* GitHub page. However, when I try to insert my own data into this code, it is not being sent to the `create()` function.

I've tried reformatting the data in various ways and ensured that it matched the template given in the *paypal-node-sdk* GitHub documentation.

My program uses ReactJS.

Here is how I'm calling the PayPal API:

```
checkoutWithPayPal = () => {

    let items = [];
    let item;
    let cart = this.state.cart;

    for (var book in cart) {
        item = {
            name: cart[book].title,
            sku: book,
            price: cart[book].price,
            currency: "USD",
            quantity: 1
        }

        items.push(item);
    }

    API.payUsingPayPal(items)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);

            for (var link in res.data.links) {
                if (res.data.links[link].rel === "approval_url") {
                    window.open(res.data.links[link].href);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Here is the axios POST request:

```
payUsingPayPal: function(items) {
    return axios.post("/api/payPal/payUsingPayPal", items);
},
```

And here is what the controller looks like that should handle the request and return the direct links to take the user to PayPal:

```
payUsingPayPal (req, res) {

    var create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://return.url",
            "cancel_url": "http://cancel.url"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": req.body
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "1.00"
            },
            "description": "This is the payment description."
        }]
    };

    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error processing payment", error);
        }

        // Used only to return axios promise
        db.Books.findOne({})
            .then(() => {
                res.json(payment);
            });
    });
}
```

When I console.log the result of `paypal.payment.create()`, I'd expect the data property to contain the redirect links that would take the user to PayPal and display the transaction info. However, the data property is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. The total of the prices in the item_list must equal the total passed into the "amount" section. Sometimes the most obvious issues are the hardest to solve....